# unable to get push notification using Urban airship push notification service?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am testing to see if i get push notification or not.so i created a account on urabnairship.com.when i send the message it says ok we sent the message but i cannot get any message on my device.does someone knows about using urbanairship.i have iphone 3g and i've turned off 3g and airplane mode and wifi is turned on.I am getting device token perfectly BTW my device is hactivated and jail broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rahul,

As I said in response to your support email (which you sent after posting this, I think), there are a few different reasons why you might have trouble receiving notifications. But now you say that your device is unlocked, and that changes things; while you got a device token, which is a good step, your device still might be having trouble connecting to Apple's push endpoints.

Best I can suggest is that you try out the [extra apsd logging mobile provision](https://devforums.apple.com/message/58759) an Apple engineer posted, to see if the connection is opening correctly. If it is (and you've gotten sandbox push notifications before), then I'd do what I said in the email, and confirm that the bundle identifier, provisioning profile, and dev/production settings all match, as that's the most common failure.

You might want to respond via the support email, though -- I certainly check that more than SO.